# How to remove deafult action bar and add toolbar instead in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am developing an app in which I have window default action bar but I want to remove that and want to add toolbar instead. How can I add that

Code for removing action bar:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".CMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
       />
```

I am extending AppCompatActivity

```
// navigation bar code
    m_Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);//finding id of drawerlayout
    s_drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, m_Drawer, m_Toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    m_Drawer.setDrawerListener(s_drawerToggle);
    m_Drawer.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    s_drawerToggle.syncState();

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        android:titleTextColor="#FFFF"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use Toolbar instead Actionbar, but can not replace success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433321/use-toolbar-instead-actionbar-but-can-not-replace-success)

Answer (score 7):

In your styles.xml set AppTheme to NoActionBar like below -

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then in your activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and add this toolbar in your layout.xml file like below -

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/primaryColor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your xml layout to add a toolbar:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Then in your Java class:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");
```

To remove default action bar, in your manifest file add

```
    <android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

or in your styles.xml add:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 1):

place this code in activity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.ideabiz.riderapplication.ui.KmsActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_kms" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

place this code in content xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ideabiz.riderapplication.ui.KmsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_kms">
```

place this in java file:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have 3 folders inside "res" folder

- values
- values-v11
- values-v14

You need to change `style.xml` file from all this folders to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

in case you have included values-v21 same for that.

now extend your `MainActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`(Which you are doing) and assign your `ToolBar` as `ActionBar`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. if not tell me what error getting after doing that.

**Update :**

Add this another style to your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="NoActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

and in manifest.xml file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".CMainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBarStyle" />
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: I am chaning for particular activity not for whole app

Comment: while doing that ...i m getting error in setSupportActionBar(m_Toolbar);

Comment: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: as you want to include toolbar for particular activity. see my updated answer.